# Proving algebraic identities: $\binom{n}{r}+\binom{n+1}{r}+\binom{n+2}{r}=\binom{n+3}{r+1}$

Tags: combinatorics

Could someone show how:
$$\binom{n}{r}+\binom{n+1}{r}+\binom{n+2}{r}=\binom{n+3}{r+1}?$$ 
I tried expanding but in the end nothing really got cancelled to prove the identity.

Comment: your equality should be $\binom{n+4}{r+1}-\binom{n}{r+1}$

Comment: your equality is still invalid

Answer (score 1):

Your claimed equality doesn't hold.

Note that for natural numbers $a \ge b \ge 0$

$$
\binom{a}{b} + \binom{a}{b+1} = \binom{a+1}{b+1}
$$
(This is known as Pascal's rule.)
Now

$
\begin{align*}
\binom{n+3}{r+1} &= \binom{n+2}{r} + \binom{n+2}{r+1} \\
&= \binom{n+2}{r} + \binom{n+1}{r} + \binom{n+1}{r+1} \\
&= \binom{n+2}{r} + \binom{n+1}{r} + \binom{n}{r} + \binom{n}{r+1} \\
&> \binom{n+2}{r} + \binom{n+1}{r} + \binom{n}{r} 
\end{align*}
$

Comment: $\binom{n}{r} + \binom{n+1}{r} + \binom{n+2}{r} + \binom{n+3}{r} \neq \binom{n+1}{r+1} + \binom{n+3}{r+1} $, try $n=1$, $r=1$. Here you applied the Pascal's Identity wrongly.

Comment: @SubhadeepDey Thanks for spotting my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Let $$ S=\binom{n}{r}+\binom{n+1}{r}+\binom{n+2}{r}$$ add both sides $\binom{n}{r+1}$ we get

$$S+\binom{n}{r+1}=\underbrace{\binom{n}{r}+\binom{n}{r+1}}+\binom{n+1}{r}+\binom{n+2}{r}$$ and the quantity above the brace is $\binom{n+1}{r+1}$ and repeatedly using it we get

$$S=\binom{n+3}{r+1}-\binom{n}{r+1}$$

Answer (score 0):

This equality does not hold for general $n,r.$ Take $n=2,\ r=1$ then the left hand side is $2+3+4=9$ but the right hand side is 10.

The hockey stick pattern corresponds to the identity

$$\binom{n}{0}+\binom{n+1}{1}+\binom{n+2}{2}=\binom{n+3}{2}$$

or more generally

$$\sum_{r=0}^k\binom{n+r}{r}=\binom{n+k+1}{k}$$

which follows from repeated (inductive) application of Pascal's identity.

Comment: I believe his $nCr$ means the combinations of $r$ elements among $n$, or $\binom{n}{r}$. Indeed, see the edit :).

Comment: OK got it meanwhile but the equality is still false :-(

Comment: Indeed. I wonder where OP got it?

Comment: I edited it. Someone edited my post inaccurately, now it is correct.

Comment: Unfortunately even this identity is false. Take $n=2,r=1$ then the LHS is 9 and the RHS is 10.

Comment: If you're wondering where this identity came from it is from here: http://mathforum.org/mathimages/imgUpload/thumb/Pascalhockey.jpg/320px-Pascalhockey.jpg I saw it rewritten like this. It's called a hockey stick pattern

Comment: Your identity does not correspond to those drawings.

Comment: Could you correct it then? It's generalized for the hockey stick pattern

Comment: OK added this to my reply.

Answer (score 0):

By inspection (each term of) your left hand side is a polynomial expression in $n$ of degree $r$, while the right hand side is a polynomial expression in $n$ of degree $r+1$. So this cannot be true.